# Java's equivalent of C# Big Rational

Tags: java, precision, biginteger

I'm currently working on project which needs absolutely exact precision - no approximation at all. Is there in Java anything like BigRational in C# ? Java's BigDecimal doesn't seem like good enough.

Comment: Yes, and it's [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Why doesn't it seem like good enough?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch A proper big rational type can represent 1/3 exactly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Really? What about 1/10?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The point of a rational type is that it can represent all rational numbers exactly, not just those where the denominator is a power of ten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not (if you don't like BigDecimal); however, you can make a class to represent it using BigInteger and BigDecimal. An example is found [here.](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/BigRational.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [Uncommons Maths](http://maths.uncommons.org/) library has a [Rational](http://maths.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/maths/number/Rational.html) type, which is probably what you're looking for.  It avoids loss of precision.